# Why can't I get the Vimeo api working?

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I should be able to use vimeo's Froogaloop library to interact with the videos, but I'm having trouble getting it going.

I thought that when Froogaloop is loaded it would automatically attach the api() and addEvent() functions to all the iframe elements, but that doesn't seem to be true.

Ultimately, I need to hook into the 'finish' event.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/xa2Dt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there were several things wrong with that code:

1. Froogaloop **does not** automatically add the api functions to vimeo iframes when it loads
2. The iframe must have a source url that specifies a `player_id` via query string parameter (eg `http://player.vimeo.com/video/1325670?api=1&player_id=sb-player`
3. The `player_id` must be the same as the id of the iframe
4. And probably some other stuff i'm forgetting right now

I have a thread of jsFiddle attempts documented on [the Vimeo Forums](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:73274#comment_7800534).  Ultimately, I got the most value out of a simple vimeo api script that i converted into [another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/G7YTx/1/).

Best of luck.  It's kind of messy stuff.